# Avoid 'warning: declaration UserSuppliedStruct does not declare anything' in gperf output file

Tags: c++, gcc, gperf

Given such a gperf file with [User-supplied struct](https://www.gnu.org/software/gperf/manual/gperf.html#User_002dsupplied-Struct):

```
%define class-name Table
%define lookup-function-name m

%struct-type
%language=C++

%{
#include <cstring>
#include <cstdio>
// defination of LookupTableElement is put to a header file in the real project and included in
namespace bar {
  struct LookupTableElement {
    const char *name;
    void (*func) ();
  };
}

// a handler
void ack() {
  puts("you said hello");
}

// namespace bar {
%}
struct bar::LookupTableElement;//gperf needs the declaration
%%
######
hello,     ack
######
%%
// } // end namespace bar
int main() {
  auto p = Table::m("hello", sizeof("hello") - 1);
  if (!p) return 1;
  p->func();
  return 0;
}
```

To compile:

```
$ gperf foo.gperf > foo.cc && g++ -std=c++0x foo.cc
```

makes g++ (gcc 4.7.3 and 4.8.2 tested) warn:

```
foo.gperf:26:13: warning: declaration ‘struct bar::LookupTableElement’ does not declare anything [enabled by default]
struct bar::LookupTableElement;//declare look up table's element
            ^
```

If `namespace bar` is removed, there will be no warning anymore.

What's the best way to avoid the warning?

1. Should I define bar::LookupTableElement in each gperf file (there are more than one gperf using the struct)?
2. Or use something like  (haven't found the switch to turn it off in GCC manual)?
3. Uncommment `// namespace bar {` and `// } // end namespace bar` and change `struct bar::LookupTableElement` to `struct LookupTableElement`. But in this way we will drag a lot of stuff into the namespace (have a look at the generated foo.cc you'd know that).
4. Any other idea?

Comment: This statement have no effect, as gcc points out. It should be `struct bar::LookupTableElement;` or `class bar::LookupTableElement;`, depending on what it is.

Comment: @keltar Thanks for the reply. But it makes no difference adding struct or class keyword. The warning is still there. I'd update the question.

Comment: @MapX We need more code

Comment: @MapX could you please make minimal example? I just did it with simple struct in separate `.h` (and `struct` declaration) and it compiles just fine.

Comment: You make a forward declaration after the actual declaration? I have never seen something like that. What happens if you remove the line with the warning?

Comment: @user2799037 [gperf grammar](https://www.gnu.org/software/gperf/manual/gperf.html#User_002dsupplied-Struct) needs that declaration.

Comment: @keltar example added. If there's no namespace prefix before the struct name it works.

Comment: @MapX Can you move the line before the definition of LookupTableElement and see what happens?

Comment: @MapX uncomment your `namespace bar {` and `}` lines and make declaration `struct LookupTableElement;`. Compiler don't know that `bar::` is namespace, because it doesn't have to be.

Comment: @user2799037 I put the defination of LookupTableElement just above int main(), it makes an error (as well as other errors):
`error: ‘bar’ has not been declared`
You could also try it if you have gperf. It's a complete example.

Comment: @keltar Yes, it's a workaround, except that the generated class are added into the namespace bar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an option to gperf:

```
   -T, --omit-struct-type
          Prevents  the  transfer  of  the type declaration to the output file. Use
          this option if the type is already defined elsewhere.
```

So, without any namespaces tricks,

```
struct bar::LookupTableElement;
```

and this option it generates completely acceptable code (e.g. `gperf -T foo.gperf > foo.gperf.cpp`).